# What happens if I set a class property via an instance of that class?

Tags: python

**Edit**: Please note that I used the wrong term "property" here. Instead I used a class *variable* ("field" in other programming languages).

If I set a class (or static) property of a class via an instance of that class, the property of this instance references the newly set object, but the class or other instances reference the object that was set on the class level:

```
class ClassPropertyDemo:
    some_value = 42

cpd_1 = ClassPropertyDemo()
cpd_2 = ClassPropertyDemo()

# Set some_value via the second instance
cpd_2.some_value = 21

print(ClassPropertyDemo.some_value)  # 42 - The value of the class property
print(cpd_1.some_value)              # 42 - The value of the class property
print(cpd_2.some_value)              # 21 - The value set to the property of the class instance
```

My question is what actually happens here. Is `cpd_2.some_value` a new *instance* property, dynamically created, that hides the class property?

Comment: Yes, you create a new instance attribute (a property is something different) like it is done by e. g. `self.some_value = 21` often seen in `__init__`.

Comment: The lookup order is important, but basically it feels like overwriting the class property. Since you are looking up the instance attribute with the same name first, the class attribute is hidden / shaded / shadowed.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Thanks for noting my error. But even "attribute" is not perfectly clear., since an attribute is "any name following a dot" (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). I think that "class variable" is the right term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your code to make it even clearer by adding:

```
del cpd_2.some_value
print(cpd_2.some_value)              # 42 - 'Unhide' the original value
```

Comment: I assume that the actual answer is "Yes, when overwriting class attributes via an instance  a new instance attribute is created" and accept this answer :-)